# Php number each query result

Tags: php, mysqli

I am making a leaderboard, I want to number it like 1st place 2nd place etc in a html table field.

How to I number each row of information coming out?
Something like 
`$result + 1`  ?

My query

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM playerdata WHERE Admin='0' ORDER BY Bank DESC LIMIT 1");

                            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
$bank = $row['bank'];
```

}

Thanks.

Comment: If you're using a loop to read the records from $result; use an incrementing value in that loop

Comment: You shall not use the SQL query to do such formatting. When iterating through `$result`, use a loop counter.

Comment: Added the loop. Please review it

Answer (score 2):

You can sort through the query results using:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM playerdata WHERE Admin='0' ORDER BY Bank DESC LIMIT 900");
$rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

for($x = 1; $x <= $rows; $x++) {
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    echo "#{$x} " . $row['bank'];
}
```

This will start counting down, showing "#1... #2... #3..." etc. You can also do this with your while loop:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM playerdata WHERE Admin='0' ORDER BY Bank DESC LIMIT 900");

$x = 1;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $bank = $row['bank'];
    echo "#{$x} " . $bank;
    $x++;
}
```

Comment: Um, the first code works, but I can't get any information such as $row['bank'];

Comment: Updated 2nd code with your "LIMIT 900" sql change. See if it works as expected.

Comment: It has the same outcome as the first code, it just numbers the results. But doesn't result an result such as bank

Comment: What are you talking about?  Do a var_dump($row) and see what you get in a specific fetch.  This has nothing to do with your question, or you don't seem to understand how to phrase what you're looking for adequately.

Comment: In your query, you used "Bank" (capital B) but in your code, you used "bank" (lowercase b) - which is it? PHP is case sensitive, you know.

Answer (score 0):

With query itself you can build the result, I think this is what u needed. Not sure

```
SELECT    @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank, a.*
FROM      playerdata a, (SELECT @curRank := 0) r
WHERE Admin='0' ORDER BY Bank DESC LIMIT 900
```

In `php`

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT    @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank, a.*
    FROM      playerdata a, (SELECT @curRank := 0) r
    WHERE Admin='0' ORDER BY Bank DESC LIMIT 900");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $rank = $row['rank'];
    $bank = $row['Bank'];
}
```